# How to use Swift localization for JSON files?

Tags: json, swift, localization

I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode 9, and I have some trouble with localizing the project. It receives its data from a JSON file, in which all strings are in English. So, I would like to localize my project and add another language to it, but I don't know how to do that, when your strings are from JSON file. I guess, for a string from that file I can't use `NSLocalizedString`, so maybe there is another way to do that.

I also hope, there is a better way for solving this problem, rather than creating a new file with JSON data in a new language. 
I've just seen the video from WWDC 2017 session 401 Localizing with Xcode 9, and now it is quite straightforward to use localization, but there is nothing about the situations like this one.
 If someone knows how to do localization for cases when the project uses a file with JSON data, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: This is usually solved by using enum strings which correspond to localized texts in the project.

Comment: @the4kman, could you provide more information about that, please, because I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by saying "enum strings which correspond to localized texts".

Comment: In other words: don't store actual strings in your JSON. Store strings that correspond to a text key in your localizable strings file.

Comment: @the4kman, ok now I understand what you are saying. But what if I get that  text from an API, so it isn't static and can change each day, for example?

Comment: If the data is dynamic, then the API should handle this. Ideally, you would pass a locale code to the API and it should return the according strings.